# Show Information from input & select field in a bootstrap model using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple input fields and 2 select fields and I have given them all a class of inputValue. When the user fills out the form I want to display all their information in a bootstrap modal.

I have been trying to get the value of the input and then get the index. Similar to how it is done [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname2)

Currently Im gettting an Uncaught ReferenceError error as show below which is strange and I cant work out why.

I hope this makes sense.

```css
const modalText = document.gteElementById('modalText')
const inputValue = document.getElementsByClassName("inputValue");

function submitSomeText() {
  modalText.text("Please confirm this info: " + "Company: " + inputValue[0].value +
  "Address Line One " + inputValue[1].value + "City/Town: " + inputValue[2].value  + "Post Code: " + inputValue[3].value + "COMMODITIES " + inputValue[4].value + "Storage Type" + inputValue[5].value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">Company</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey" name="CollectionCompany" type="text" placeholder="Company" class=" input-border ">
    <p class="help-block"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label inputValue">Address Line One</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="Street address, P.O. Box, Company Name..." class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">City/Town</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="City/Town" class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <p class="mb-1 text-uppercase left mb-0">Commodities</p>
  <select name="Address" class="classic text-uppercase center w-100 mb-4 inputValue" name="PalletType" id="grey">
    <option selected >Food</option>
    <option>Plants</option>
    <option>Electronics</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <p class="mb-1 text-uppercase left mb-0">Storage Type</p>
  <select name="Address" class="classic text-uppercase center w-100 mb-4 inputValue" name="PalletType" id="grey">
    <option selected >Ambient</option>
    <option>Refrigerated</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onClick="submitText()">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalText">
   
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: You have "gteElementById" instead of "getElementById".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes here:

1. You have placed an `onclick` on the button with function `submitText` but the function name in js is `submitSomeText()`
2. You are selecting your inputs by giving each `input` element a class of `inputValue` but you, and I assume mistakenly, put a class `inputValue` to a label and when you try to get its value it'll return undefined.
3. `modalText.text()` text is not a function rather a property that has to be assigned a value through an assignment operator `=`
4. You also have a typo instead of `gteElementById` it should be *`getElementById`* notice the word "get"

```js
const modalText = document.getElementById('modalText')
const inputValue = document.getElementsByClassName("inputValue");

function submitSomeText() {

  modalText.text = "Please confirm this info: " + "Company: " + inputValue[0].value +
    "Address Line One " + inputValue[1].value + "City/Town: " + inputValue[2].value + "Post Code: " + inputValue[3].value + "COMMODITIES " + inputValue[4].value + "Storage Type" + inputValue[5].value;
  console.log(modalText.text)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">Company</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey" name="CollectionCompany" type="text" placeholder="Company" class=" input-border ">
    <p class="help-block"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
<!-- NOTE you added inputValue class to a label and trying to get its value will gives you undefined-->
  <label class="control-label">Address Line One</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="Street address, P.O. Box, Company Name..." class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">City/Town</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="City/Town" class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group ">
  <label class="control-label">Postal Code</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="input-border collection-input inputValue" id="grey formGroupExampleInput" name="CollectionAddress" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" class=" input-border">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <p class="mb-1 text-uppercase left mb-0">Commodities</p>
  <select name="Address" class="classic text-uppercase center w-100 mb-4 inputValue" name="PalletType" id="grey">
    <option selected>Food</option>
    <option>Plants</option>
    <option>Electronics</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <p class="mb-1 text-uppercase left mb-0">Storage Type</p>
  <select name="Address" class="classic text-uppercase center w-100 mb-4 inputValue" name="PalletType" id="grey">
    <option selected>Ambient</option>
    <option>Refrigerated</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onClick="submitSomeText()">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalText">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```